# Should I use the word "object" as a singular or plural noun?

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing a paper. I wrote, "Many phenomena that heavier objects are reported to fall faster than the lighter ones are observed." However, Microsoft Word corrected to "object." Which one is right? And how I can

Comment: You should trust your instincts.  MS Word is not known for its intelligence!

Comment: So was I right?

Comment: See below, you were right, but ...

Comment: Also, my copy of MS Word does not correct or suggest a correction based upon this sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The plural of [object is objects.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/object)

You sentence, on the other hand, has some other issues.

Many *phenomena* is not the word choice you should be using here.  You are speaking about many instances of *one* phenomenon.  The observation that heavier objects fall faster than lighter ones.

You could say:

> There are many observational reports that heavier objects fall faster than lighter ones.  Clearly this is not true because acceleration is constant regardless of mass.